# Usage of "w.r.t." in academic papers

Tags: technical

Is it possible to use the abbreviation "w.r.t." in academic papers?

Comment: No, it is not advisable.

Comment: Your title says technical papers and your question body says academic papers.  Which is it?

Comment: Academic, so technical.

Comment: @user278064: They aren't synonyms or even overlapping, really.  Academic writing and technical writing are vastly different styles.

Comment: "Possible"? Yes.  In fact, in a mathematics paper one would write "w.r.t." meaning "with respect to" and no one would think twice about it.

Comment: @chaos they usually are synonyms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible, but it's a bad idea.  It's not part of the conventions of academic writing, so will typically be read as clashing in style with it.

Comment: Academic writing conventions vary between fields. Justaskin_ is correct to say that it would be fine in a maths paper.

Answer (score 16):

In mathematics "w.r.t." is part of the standard jargon. It is not unusual to see it used (sparingly) in peer-reviewed journal articles.

Comment: Here is an example, where you can find w.r.t. https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.1624

Answer (score 3):

See,

> With Regard To (or) with reference to

I think is supposed to be written in papers or letters in order **to direct attention towards or to refer to** something that was being discussed immediately before these words... OK?

Now, I think in *technical* or *academic* papers using **"w.r.t"** abbreviation for **"With Regard To"** may not be incorrect, but it may be **misleading or ambiguous.** As  **"w.r.t"** may stand for something else as well. For Example it may stand for **"Windowed Radon Transform"** and if something like this is a part of the discussion, then use of such abbreviation is uncalled for.

Comment: When I see *w.r.t.* I interpret it as *with respect to*.  Per [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=with+respect+to%2Cwith+regard+to%2Cwith+reference+to%2CWith+respect+to%2CWith+regard+to%2CWith+reference+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *with respect to,with regard to,with reference to,With respect to,With regard to,With reference to*, phrase *with respect to* occurs more often than either phrase you mentioned.

Comment: Wouldn't "Windowed Radon Transform" be WRT instead of w.r.t.?

Answer (score -2):

David Foster Wallace uses this abbreviation all the time. It's awesome. Depends on the tone you are going for; DFW uses it to evidence his desire for efficient language is on balance with his sprawling analysis of 'ineffable' artistic topics.

I agree with it's use in a mathematician's paper, as efficiency is prized in that study. History, humanities, etc - it's a no go.

Oh yeah, I'm a mere BA holder, so account for that in your advice acceptance criteria.

Comment: You might want to back this up with some sources and further explanation. In its current form, this is not a strong answer. Thank you!